# load and read sift features of image

Tags: python, sift

Below code is for to save image features to a csv format file.This code is working.
I want to load and read feature from file.Can any one give me python code for this.?
Anyone help me please.

```
img1 = cv2.imread("/Users/alisa/Desktop/sift.jpg")

gr_img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(gr_img1, None)

filename = '/Users/alisa/Desktop/q.csv'

gr_img1 = ''

for row_features in des1:

for feature in row_features:

gr_img1 = gr_img1 + str(feature) + ','

with open(filename, 'w+') as output:

output.write(gr_img1 + "\n")`
```

Comment: Have you read anything about reading and writing into files in python? This is way too broad of question... what have you tried so far?

Comment: When I find nothing then I post here.